# Where are the master illusion spell text?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In skyrim i have 100 skill in illusion and i went to the illusion master in the college of winterhold. He gave me a quest to find text books that have the information i need to get the master illusion spells. I need to use a spell he gives me to see the books, but i can't find the text books i need for the master illusion spells , i searched everwhere even in the midden. Does anyone know where i could find the text books?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From UESP:

1. Find the book in the Arcanaeum (same table as Legend of Red Eagle book)
2. Find the book in Hall of Attainment (under a bench on the landing of
   the upper level)
3. Find the book in Hall of Countenance (on a barrel in the upstairs
   storeroom)
4. Find the book in The Midden (table next to the Atronach Forge)

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Illusion_Ritual_Spell

Comment: Thanks tom i look at some of those places but i was looking too fast i knew i probably missed them